# Is there a way to export the .edmx diagram from VS2008 to Visio?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, visio

Some people want to see the DB structure and dont have VS, is there a way to do this?  Or any other way to export it outside of a screencapture (it is a huge diagram).

Thank you.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can right click on the design surface and select Diagram -> Export as Image and you get the entire edmx model generated as bmp

Comment: The image export is okay, but it would still be extremely useful if I could export and .edmx to Visio or if Visio could import an .edmx file.

Comment: The problem of doing this is that the image obtained gets pixelated.Better using a pdf printer such as PDFCreator, and set paper size to ARCH E3 and export it to png.

Answer (score 35):

This doesn't really work on large diagrams.  Oh it exports it, but on a large diagram, once you zoom in, all text is nothing but pixels.  It's a logged bug, but right now Microsoft is not planning on fixing this issue.

What I've done is downloaded a pdf printer (like Bullzip free edition), then just "print" the document to pdf.

To Viso, no.  I have yet to find a way to export this to Visio.

Comment: Thanks for the PDF printing tip. Saved me about 3 hours.

Comment: The problem with printing is that it 1. disregards manually-placed relationship lines, and 2. hides cardinality

Answer (score 12):

There is a **PDF** generation solution *(suitable if you have large diagrams)* :

You can do it from Visual Studio :

1. `File > Print`
2. Send it to `OneNote` or choose `PDF`.

Comment: Very K.I.S.S. of you. :)